# Make .netrc authentication work with aiohttp

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, aiohttp, .netrc

I'd like to use a `.netrc` file with credentials to authenticate to an API using aiohttp. As far as I can tell this should be possible, as long as the file is in the home directory (or the relevant env variable set correctly) and `trust_env=True` set in the `aiohttp.ClientSession`.

But whatever I try, I get a `401` response. I've checked with requests, and it works just fine. I've browsed through the [relevant code](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/08ca779e9abdb6d558cdd1647fdca17cfe979711/aiohttp/helpers.py#L252-L280) and it seems like it'll only pick up the credentials if a proxy is supplied. Can someone explain?

Here's an example that reproduces the issue:

First put a `.netrc` file in home directory:

```sh
machine httpbin.org
    login foo
    password bar
```

```py
import aiohttp
import requests

url = "http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/foo/bar"

with requests.Session() as sess:
    r = sess.get(url)
    r.raise_for_status()

# no exception raised

async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
    r = await session.get(url)
    r.raise_for_status()

# exception raised
```

> ClientResponseError: 401, message='UNAUTHORIZED',
> url=URL('http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/foo/bar')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand in the doc, the `trust_env` and `.netrc` credentials are only used for proxy authentication, not for regular server authentication.

For authentication to the server directly, the docs say that you have to use a `BasicAuth` object (as you surely know), but to use the `.netrc` file, one solution would be to use a custom authentication class, eg:

```py
class NetrcAuth(aiohttp.BasicAuth):
    def __new__(cls, host):
        login, account, password = netrc.netrc().authenticators(host)
        return super().__new__(cls, login=login, password=password)
```

that you could then use as

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

hostname = urlparse(url).hostname

async with aiohttp.ClientSession(auth=NetrcAuth(hostname)) as session:
    r = await session.get(url)
    r.raise_for_status()
```

Of course this is not optimal, as we would like to have the `ClientSession` take care of that for us, but it's maybe a step in the right direction?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess it *technically* solves my problem, as you can work with `.netrc`. Unfortunately it doesn't help on a practical level as I need to know the hostname on a per-request basis. The desired behavior (as `requests.Session`) is that you can pass in different URLs to the same session, and auth gets applied based on a per-host basis automatically.

Comment: yes, this is of course far from optimal. Let's hope this gets implemented in aiohttp some day.